# Getting NotConnectedException error on running selenium webdriver test from Bamboo in Centos 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, centos, webdriver, bamboo

I am trying to run the selenium tests from bamboo in cantos VM. But it display the error org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

I am using Selenium Standalone Server 2.52.0 and tried with following FF versions but getting the same error

FF 38
FF 45
FF 44
FF 40

Anybody helps to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set the path of user.dir upto the bin directory where the firefox is installed.